# Триггеры в Postgres

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Здравствуйте! Был написан триггер для добавления записи в БД. Суть его в том, что первое поле id должно заполняться через одну цифру. То есть не 1, 2, 3, 4 и т. д., а 1, 3, 5 и т. д. Триггер вроде считался, но при попытке добавления записи получаю ошибку:

```
ОШИБКА:  подзапрос должен вернуть только одну колонку
LINE 1: SELECT (SELECT * FROM prep WHERE prep.id_prep = NEW.id_prep)
               ^
QUERY:  SELECT (SELECT * FROM prep WHERE prep.id_prep = NEW.id_prep)
CONTEXT:  функция PL/pgSQL add_id_prep(), строка 3, оператор IF
********** Ошибка **********
ОШИБКА: подзапрос должен вернуть только одну колонку
SQL-состояние: 42601
Контекст: функция PL/pgSQL add_id_prep(), строка 3, оператор IF
```

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_id_prep() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT * FROM prep WHERE prep.id_prep+2 = NEW.id_prep) 
    THEN
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;
        END IF;
        END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER newtrigger 
    AFTER INSERT ON prep FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_id_prep();
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти и исправить ошибку.

Comment: А что ее искать, тебе написано что вложенный запрос должен возвращать одну колонку, и вообще использование * само по себе не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_prep 
    INCREMENT 2 
    MINVALUE 1;

INSERT INTO prep (id_prep, ...)
    SELECT nextval('seq_prep'), ...;
```